# Ensuring two slanted divs are always connected vertically with no spacing

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I've got the following layout - I'm trying to ensure the two divs are always aligned one below the other regardless of screen size, and there is no empty white space between them. When I set `margin-top: 15%` on `div2` on a large display, this works fine, however when I shrink the screen size, I need a value closer to `20%`. How can I ensure these two divs are always aligned?

```css
#div1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #6303B1, #ff0099);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 10%, 100% 0px, 100% 90%, 0px 100%);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#div2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #6303B1, #ff0099);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 10%, 100% 0px, 100% 90%, 0px 100%);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>hi</p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the use of `vw` unit inside clip-path and margin. I considered `5vw` but you can adjust it like you want:

```css
#div2 {
  margin-top:-5vw;
}

[id] {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #6303B1, #ff0099);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 5vw, 100% 0px, 100% calc(100% - 5vw), 0px 100%);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>hi</p>

  </div>
</section>
```

A pixel value can also do the job:

```css
#div2 {
  margin-top:-40px;
}

[id] {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #6303B1, #ff0099);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 40px, 100% 0px, 100% calc(100% - 40px), 0px 100%);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>hi</p>

  </div>
</section>
```